# How to do unwrappin inside If-let statement?

Tags: swift, optional-parameters

I am using `if let` for getting the object if its not nil. But I also need to check other condition as well i.e., if `"treatmentContext.patientTreatment.canWritePermissions.contains(treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner"`. That I am able to do by putting comma after the first statement but here the issue is, I need to unwrap the value of `treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner` and here I don't know where exactly I need to unwrap that so that my if condition gets pass when it meets all the criteria.
Below is the code for reference.

```
if let treatmentContext = IoC.resolve(Treatment.self, from: .treatment), treatmentContext.patientTreatment.canWritePermissions.contains(treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner) 
     {
    self.presentNavigation(isNew: isNew)
    }
```

Comment: `if let treatmentContext = IoC.resolve(Treatment.self, from: .treatment), let owner = treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner, treatmentContext.patientTreatment.canWritePermissions.contains(owner) { self.presentNavigation(isNew: isNew) }`

Comment: @NiravD Thanks bro. Just to suggest that always post you answer as an Answer not in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know you can separate the conditions with `,`, so just do that again, but this time it's another optional binding clause:

```
if let treatmentContext = IoC.resolve(Treatment.self, from: .treatment), 
   let owner = treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner,
   treatmentContext.patientTreatment.canWritePermissions.contains(owner) {
    self.presentNavigation(isNew: isNew)
}
```

You can separate any number of optional binding clauses, `Bool` conditions, or `case ...` patterns with `,` in an if.

Comment: It is working but could you please let me know why I don't need to write if before """"let owner = treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner,"""". Shouldn't it be """"if let owner = treatmentContext.pathPatientTreatment.owner,""""? This is what made me confused.

Comment: @Developer Contrary to popular believe, `if let` isn't a "single thing". The syntax is actually `if`, and then one or more comma separated "clauses". The clauses can be `let x = y`, `Bool` expressions, or `case ` patterns.